# Could US mayors/governors order their state police to arrest unmarked federal agents?

Tags: united-states, police, federalism

Could the local US governors/mayors, who reject federal agents on their streets, legally order their local police force to arrest all people, who are violence and don't wear any insignia?

Or would it be illegal for them to arrest the federal agents, even when they don't wear any insignia showing their role as federal agents?

Comment: Welcome to LSE and thanks for the nice question! Your question is simple to ask, but the answer is complicated. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: @Justaguy The edited version of your answer covers the main points, thank you. I find it puzzling though, that the US allows unmarked officers. This allows for the establishment of secret police that can not be made accountable..

Comment: I agree completely. Here two factors that make the lack a bit more understandable. First, Federal LEOs are usually deployed where their identity is obvious, such as in customs raids or at the border, so the lack of id wasn't an issue. Second, many (most?) police departments have *policies* requiring officers to identify themselves. When those policies work well, nobody will push for a law. https://boingboing.net/2015/02/25/think-you-have-the-right-to-de.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Revised for clarity in light of comments**

1. State and local police can **arrest anyone** who they have **probable cause** to believe is breaking state or local law.
2. Like all LEOs, Federal LEOs **can break some** state and local laws while **enforcing Federal law.** When they [grab someone off the street](https://www.washingtonpost.com/outlook/2020/07/29/arrests-portland-unconstitutional-qualified-immunity/) and hold them in a cell, they are *detaining* them, not *kidnapping* them, and so on. However, **to avoid arrest,** the Feds *have to identify themselves.* That's because state and local LEO who know they are dealing with Feds on federal business no longer have *probable cause* to believe a crime is being committed.
3. State and local police **can arrest** Federal LEOs who they: a) have probable cause to believe are breaking state or local; *and,* b) have no reason to believe are Feds enforcing Federal law. In other words: *Any Fed who refuses to identify herself* to a local LEO can be arrested *if there is probable cause.*
4. State and local police **cannot**, however, arrest Federal LEOs just because they are **not wearing insignias.** That is because: a) *there are no federal statutes requiring federal LEOs to identify themselves*; b) the [Supremacy Clause](https://www.law.cornell.edu/wex/supremacy_clause) says federal law takes precedence over state and local law *that conflict with it*; c) at least in Portland, the feds were not operating under any sort of formal agreement with Portland or Oregon officials that required them to have identification.

While it is hard to prove a negative, the question of whether Federal LEOs are required to identify themselves has been looked at recently by reputable sources. They all agree there is no such law. For example, the answer from [Lawfare](https://www.lawfareblog.com/can-law-enforcement-officers-refuse-identify-themselves):

> Broadly speaking, **law enforcement officers do not have a legal duty to disclose** either their identities or their agencies of affiliation, **even if asked directly.** Certain municipalities require police officers to identify themselves if asked, but there is **currently no federal statute** requiring officer disclosure of such information.

The article points out that the two main types of cases involving police identifying themselves really don't apply: police who are working undercover, notably in sting operations, and police searching and seizing property.

They go on to point out:

> Separate from the question of federal law, **several states have adopted laws and regulations requiring law enforcement to identify themselves.** For example, under New York City’s Right to Know Act, a broad set of police reforms that went into effect in October 2018, officers must tell civilians at the start of some interactions “their name, rank, command, and shield number.”

(Also, many departments have *policies* that generally require officers to identify themselves, although with exceptions. You can see examples of the policies [here](https://boingboing.net/2015/02/25/think-you-have-the-right-to-de.html).)

Again, these *local laws do not apply to Feds because of the Supremacy Clause.*

**NOTE:** As several of the news stories note, the lack of identification will make it very hard to hold Federal LEOs accountable for their actions. **Accountability requires identity.**

Comment: Wouldn't a federal "policeman" standing in New York need to follow NY law and identify themselves accordingly.

Comment: This strikes me as problematic. If federal agents do not identify themselves and their affiliation, under what rule should citizens obey their orders? In other words, if men walk up in mismatched, ambiguous uniforms and order a citizen to get into an unmarked van, isn't that citizen within his legal rights to refuse to comply, or even to defend him/herself with due force?

Comment: Whether the federal LEO is legally required to identify him/herself is a different question than whether the local police can detain the federal LEO if there is probably cause that a law is violated if they weren't an LEO, and their LEO status is not verified.

Comment: @TedWrigley I agree. I think the current law is terrible, and creates unnecessary problems. But that does not change the fact that under current law, most LEO, including Federal LEO do not have to identify themselves. (Also, remember this is a question about state and local police arresting Federal LEO for being "unmarked.")

Comment: @user102008 You are absolutely correct. I've re-written the answer to make this distinction clearer. (I did, however, skip the important question of what it would take for a Federal LEO to prove she was a Fed on duty enforcing federal law.)

Comment: @GeorgeWhite Thanks. I rewrote this to make this point clearer. Under the *Supremacy Clause,* federal law that conflict with state/local laws take precedence. This prevents states from passing laws that make it harder for federal agents to enforce federal law. Of course, federal statutes and Department regulations may require Federal LEOs to obey state law.

Comment: @TedWrigley  I agree: The current law is bad, and creates unnecessary problems for law-abiding citizens. But it *is the law.* The problems created for state and local police are different than those created for law-abiding citizens. (My sense, for what it's worth, is that in PDX, the locals didn't have any problems identifying the Feds. The problem, as you say, was with citizens identifying the Feds.)

Comment: @user102008: That is not exactly true. Remember, US law has distinct 'color of authority' principles that allow law enforcement to be charged for executing criminal acts under the pretense that they are authorized to do so. Federal agents who act anonymously could certainly be charged with with assault and kidnapping under color of authority; the onus would be on them to prove to the DA or Court's satisfaction that their actions were legally justified.

Comment: I understand that a federal official in the proper conduct of their statutorily allowed activities can't be breaking a state law. But if they are not acting within their legally authorized activities there is not a supremacy issue.

Comment: @Justaguy: Officers/agents may not need to identify themselves *personally*, but they *do* need to identify their affiliation and thus their authorization to carry out enforcement action under the law. If they do not identify an affiliation, there is no reason to assume they have legal authority to carry out enforcement actions. Otherwise, the only reason to comply with these people is the fact that they have guns, and that is not consistent with the rule of law.

Comment: @GeorgeWhite I agree, but I'm not sure I see how it applies to your original comment: "Wouldn't a federal "policeman" in New York *need to follow NY law* and *identify themselves accordingly.*" My point was that *under federal law,* the Fed not wearing insignia would be "acting within their legally authorized activities."

Comment: Downvoted because undercover and plainclothes police officers need not identify themselves. Especially when protecting the identity of the agent in question E.G. deep cover scenarios. Uniformed police officers are required to identify themselves *if asked*, but that would be as simple as a name and police ID number. Furthermore, Supremacy Clause means Federal laws trump state laws, meaning even if a Federal officer, enforcing a Federal law, had violated a state law, supremacy clause would trump it.

Comment: @SSight3 1) We agree about undercover officers. I say that very few officers have to legally identify themselves. 2) You say uniformed LEOs have to identify themselves. **Do you have a source?** 3) I don't see where we disagree about the Supremacy Clause. I say: "the Supremacy Clause says federal law takes precedence over state and local law that conflict with it," and, " local laws do not apply to Feds because of the Supremacy Clause."

Comment: @SSight3 even under cover police officers have to identify themselves when they make an arrest.  As for what the Supremacy clause means, it is not enough to just read its plain wording to deduce when it applies and when it does not.  There is case law (SCOTUS ruling(s)) on how the Supremacy Clause is to be interpreted and, in the legal system, the courts's interpretation of the Constitution trumps all other interpretations.